# How to find the Name servers for my azure website?

Tags: azure

I am using azure for the first time and I am trying to point my custom domain name to my azurewebsites.net website and I am not able to find out what are the name servers. I have registered my domain name with tucows-webquarry. There I have no way to find out about managin A Records or CNAME ..
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Taka a look in here, it has print screen with what you need:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/

Comment: Thanks for answering- but I am already on that page- It says about A records and CNAme- I dont have a way to configure A Records or CNAME with my registrar- my registrar is tucows-webquarry...

Comment: I recomment you get in touch with tucows to check that. Another option: https://dnsimple.com/

Comment: That article says nothing about the NS records. See "Delegating a domain to Azure DNS" in [Delegate your domain to Azure DNS | Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/dns-domain-delegation). That explains that the registrar's NS records can (should?) point to Azure and then the other records are in Azure's zone file. That article shows how to get the nameservers but I do not understand it.

Comment: See [Azure DNS](http://samcogan.com/azure-dns). Apparently it was not available when this question was asked.